# How to switch active erlang in macport?

Tags: macos, erlang, macports

How to activate version @17.4?

I have OS X 10.9.5, MacPorts 2.3.3. And active erlang @R15B03+ssl

Do this:

```
$ sudo port list | grep erlang
erlang                         @R15B03         lang/erlang
erlsom                         @1.2.1          erlang/erlsom
log4erl                        @0.8.6          erlang/log4erl
mochiweb                       @2.7.0          erlang/mochiweb
rebar                          @2.5.1          erlang/rebar
tsung                          @1.4.2          erlang/tsung
erlang                         @17.4           lang/erlang
```

which erl:

```
/opt/local/bin/erl
```

ls -l erl:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin .... erl -> ../lib/erlang/bin/erl
```

Try to activate port activate erlang @17.4 got

```
Error: port activate failed: Registry error: erlang @17.4 is not installed.
```

Try to update/upgrade - nothing. Remove erlang totaly. Install - got installed R15B03...

How to switch to newest version?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo port install erlang @17.4`?

Comment: Of course

`--->  Computing dependencies for erlang`
`--->  Cleaning erlang`
`--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors`
`--->  No broken files found.`
`Lara-Croft:front_tpl vlad$ erl`
`Erlang R15B03 (erts-5.9.3) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]`

Comment: You cannot specify a specific version to install with MacPorts. `sudo port install erlang @17.4` will not do what you want – it will silently ignore the version number. However, erlang 17.4 is the current version in MacPorts. So running `sudo port selfupdate` followed by `sudo port upgrade erlang` or `sudo port install erlang` should give you the latest version.

Comment: There are simpler ways to install Erlang on mac: [packages](http://erlangcentral.org/downloads/) and [kerl](https://github.com/yrashk/kerl). Kerl compiles different versions of Erlang and lets you switch between them very easily. If you don't need that - packages are better.

Comment: @neverpanic Not working:

`sudo port upgrade erlang
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  No broken files found.                             
Lara-Croft:front_www vlad$ sudo port install erlang
--->  Computing dependencies for erlang
--->  Cleaning erlang
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  No broken files found.
Lara-Croft:front_www vlad$ erl
Erlang R15B03 (erts-5.9.3)`

Comment: What does `port info --version erlang` print on your system?

Comment: @R15B03....

Solve problem - reinstall ports

Comment: If it was showing R15B03 and not 17.4 (like it does for me) then your selfupdate did not work. Try `sudo port -d selfupdate` to see debug output and follow http://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ#selfupdatefails.